# Alternative Data Structure to DataTable

Tags: c#, data-structures, datatable

I need a data structure of some sort to do the following:

One "set" composed of many types such as string, integer, datetime and double.
Many sets are added dynamically
The sets are retrieved dynamically where information is pulled

Now the obvious solution is to use a DataTable.  Define the datatable structure, and add a new row each time you need to add a new set.  Pull data from the datatable when you need to.

Actually I have implemented it already using a datatable, but the problem is it is extremely slow for some reason.  Since this is done thousands to millions of times performance can be problematic.

Is there an alternative datatable type of data structure with better performance that I can use or should I build my own class using Lists<>  ?

Comment: Is the Data Type reusable or does it need to be dynamic, can you use anonymous types? It would also depend on where you are reading the Data from, DataBase, file, Queue etc as ADO.Net and the Entity Framework have a lot of inbuilt functionality.

Comment: Hey there,

The data type is reusable, once set it is static.  Only the actual data of course changes, where entries are added and removed.  I have no idea what anonymous types are.

The data are self generated, it is not read from anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your use case I would recommend using `List<object[]>` (since you mentioned dynamic schema) as central data structure, but you will need to maintain the schema info yourself if you need it later on.

If you need to bind the UI to the data this approach will add a lot of extra manual work, it's better suited for background processing of large amounts of data.

We have used this approach in the past and were able to save 2/3 of memory and 80% of execution time when bulk handling data compared to data tables.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the suggestion!  I think think this might just work, I have never worked with object[] before.  80% Execution speed?  That is faster but not by much.

Comment: That was a misunderstanding, it's not running 20% faster, it's running 80% faster due to the existing overhead in the `DbDataReader` to `DataTable` code.

Comment: Ah ok I see hehe, then it is excellent. I'm going to implement it and see what performance improvement I get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One alternative way of approaching problems like this: use a sqlite database in memory.

Sounds like a weird thing to do at first, but you can put quite complex structures into tables, and you get the whole power of SQL to work on your data. SQLite is a tiny lib, so it won't bloat up your code. Integrating the DB into your code might be kinda strange at first, put performance should work on huge data sets (since that's what DBs are made for). And if you ever need to save that data to disk, you are already done.

Depending on the details of your problem, it might even be a good idea to move to a bigger db back end (e.g. postgres), but that is hard to tell from here. Just don't dismiss this idea too easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar questions on stackoverflow, but none provides a good answer. A generic alternative should not be `List<YourObject>`, because `YourObject` is not generic. The beauty of DataTable is that it does not have a data model.

A DataTable is a collection of rows, while each row is a collection of cells. A cell could be a string or a number. So we can define a Cell as:

```
public class Cell
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Then a row would be `Dictionary<string, Cell>`, where string is the column name. And then a DataTable alternative is simply a `List<Dictionary<string, Cell>>`.

Let's say you define Rows as `public List<Dictionary<string, Cell>> Rows;`.

Now you can easily query the Rows like:

```
var MaleHeight = Rows.Where(row => row["sex"].Text == "Male").Select(row => row["Height"].Value);
```